# Android: how to let resources for phone override resources for tablet

Tags: android, tablet, android-resources

Currently in Android development it is quite common to start developing new version specially for Android Tablet. (Usually it is not additional layouts for tablet but fully new app as logic for managing fragments is quite different from logic that mobile phone version has started with.)

In out team we have Android resources values in `res/values` folder, and particularly dimension definitions inside `dimens.xml`

The problem came to light when this Tablet version is said has to work on phone as well.

Android supposes that alternative resources are put into e.g. `values-small`, `values-normal`, `values-large`, `values-xlarge`

see [Providing Resources article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), e.g. locally `sdk/docs/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html`

First it is not said explicitly in docs, but I assume that is inside is `values` actually `values-normal` i.e. default values for default screen size with default density (that is mobile phone)
**Is this suggestion right?**

Then without moving of all `values` into`values-xlarge` (because they are actually were designed with Tablet in mind), how to redefine (or "override") values in particular dimensions inside `dimens.xml` ?

I can't move because there are a lot of files, and some are under development.

[image: screen-ranges]

pic from [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) e.g. `sdk/docs/guide/practices/screens_support.html`

Related SO questions:

- [Different GUI on phone and tablet, but same app problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456087/different-gui-on-phone-and-tablet-but-same-app-problem)
- [Supporting resources for tablets and mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157886/supporting-resources-for-tablets-and-mobiles)
- [Which resource structure to use for both Android tablets and mobiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988045/which-resource-structure-to-use-for-both-android-tablets-and-mobiles)

UPDATE-1 `values` is not the same as `values-normal`, as value put into `value-small` will be read for xlarge Configuration (when there is no other configurations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First it is not said explicitly in docs, but I assume that is inside is values actually values-normal i.e. default values for default screen size with default density (that is mobile phone) Is this suggestion right?

No. `res/values/` simply does not qualify on screen size.

> Then without moving of all values intovalues-xlarge (because they are actually were designed with Tablet in mind), how to redefine (or "override") values in particular dimensions inside dimens.xml ?

Have one of every value in `res/values/`. This will be used, by default, on all screen sizes.

Then, in other resource sets, like `res/values-large/`, provide alternative definitions for select resources, where those alternatives are needed at that stated screen size **or larger**.

And, you may wish to consider switching to `-swNNNdp` and kin over the original set of screen size buckets, for more flexibility.

Comment: -swNNNdp configuration qualifier is since API level 13.

Comment: @PaulVerest: Correct. However, there are very few `large` or `xlarge` screen devices running less than API Level 13.

Comment: For confirmation: Do you say that I don't need to move to `res/values-large/` but to redefine some values in `res/values-normal/`?

Comment: @PaulVerest: I have no idea, as I did not write your app. I am merely answering your specific questions regarding the role of `res/values/` and how to override values for sizes. Since the size qualifiers are for a certain size **and larger**, you tend to put your smaller-size values in `res/values/` and override for larger sizes as needed. If you are supporting `small` screen devices, but want different resources for `normal` and larger devices, put the `small` ones in `res/values/` and the `normal`-or-larger ones in `res/values-normal/`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't move because there are a lot of files, and some are under development.

As you have already answered yourself, to solve this you need to move the files, so you just need to bite the bullet and get on with it.  The "under development" files then need to be placed in the appropriate location when they are ready.

Assuming you are using a code management system like Git, moving the files is no big deal - they still retain all their version history for example.